# how to joint table data show in one table

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-9

I have tried to join three tables and the code is:

```php
public function customersList(Request $request)
{
    $info = [];
    $data = [];
    if (!empty($request->value)) :
        $info = DB::table('customers')
            ->join('phones', 'customers.id', '=', 'phones.customer_id',)
            ->join('emails', 'customers.id', '=', 'emails.customer_id',)
            ->select('customers.id', 'customers.name', 'emails.email', 'emails.customer_id', 'phones.phone', 'phones.customer_id')
            ->where('customers.name', 'like', '%' . $request->value . '%')
            ->orWhere('emails.email', 'like', '%' . $request->value . '%')
            ->orWhere('phones.phone', 'like', '%' . $request->value . '%')
            ->get();
    else :
        $info = DB::table('customers')
            ->join('phones', 'customers.id', '=', 'phones.customer_id',)
            ->join('emails', 'customers.id', '=', 'emails.customer_id',)
            ->select('customers.id', 'customers.name', 'emails.email', 'emails.customer_id', 'phones.phone', 'phones.customer_id')
            ->get();
    endif;
}
```

Output is

[image]

But the problem is that one cutomer's record is showing more times as in console output, because one record in the customers table has a relationship with maximum two records in phone and email table.

But I want the output to be like

[image]

Is it possible by writing laravel php code? If possible then how?

Comment: Thanks for your question! Please post code and output as text instead of an image to make your question more accessible, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Don't know laravel but you can do a GROUP BY on the user id and get the phone numbers with GROUP_CONCAT() and then just explode it in php.

Comment: Thank you @Ingo Steinke. But writing as text is time consuming. Appart from that output is in console and image is taken from another trying, where my problem wasn't solved properly. NOw I would like to table image output by my existing code. Is it possible to do anything keeping my existing query builder process? Thanks again